# irregular-shaped DOM elements

Tags: html, css

How to make them in HTML or CSS?

For example:
http://draw.to/D11KGJr

I've heard about the map tag, but it seems it only generates an invisible clickable area, on which you can't apply CSS properties, like border or background.

Comment: ... That's just an image. There are no irregular shaped elements there, just a div with rounded corners containing an `<img>` tag. If you're talking about drawing a new image, it's using a `<canvas>`.

Comment: Out of interest, why do you want to do this?

Comment: I'm just curious. For example I may want to draw a map

Comment: Not an exact answer, but I have taken `<map>`s, parsed the contents and created images with matching shapes and a mid-way alpha value (not as a DOM thing, either on the server or as a set-up process that isn't done on the fly), and then overlaid them on top of the image the map is for. Could meet some possible needs for this, but it isn't all done with HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides using CSS 3 techniques as the others proposed, you could also embed SVG in your HTML document.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sn3Z9/)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <!-- <head> ... -->
  <body>
    Taken from <a href="http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:SVG_example7.svg?uselang=de">http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:SVG_example7.svg?uselang=de</a>, thanks to <a href="http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User_talk:Sarang?uselang=de">Sarang</a>!
    <hr />
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="304" height="290">
      <path d="M2,111h300 l-242.7,176.3 92.7-285.3 92.7,285.3z" fill="#FB2" stroke="#B00" stroke-width="4" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about that drawing: it's a `canvas` element.

See here for a tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Canvas_tutorial

Answer (score 1):

This is possible - within limits, and only on newer browsers - using CSS3 techniques. For an example, see this [CSS3 Twitter Fail Whale](http://www.subcide.com/experiments/fail-whale/).

Comment: Nice whale. It's not a single element though.

Comment: @RobW - true, and it was probably fairly horrible to create as well.

Comment: I was thinking it was yours, and was going to +1 just for your having done something that is simultaneously so crazily brilliant, and horribly needless.

Answer (score 1):

That uses the canvas element.

Spec:  http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-canvas-element.html#the-canvas-element

Doc based on one particular browser implementation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas

Informal docs: http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html and http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/

There are other approaches for non-rectangular elements, which may be more appropriate for what you actually need, if you can say more about your specific requirements.